# React Navigation 5 Top bar with FlatList Scrolling and Dynamic Height

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I wanted to create a similar feature of how Instagram has on their profile page, where you're able to swipe on different tabs (your posts, and posts people tagged you in).

I've tried attempting to create it using React Navigation 5's Top Tab Navigator https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator and FlatList, but not sure if its the correct way of doing it.

**Profile Screen Component**

```js
const ProfileScreen = () => (
  <>
    <FlatList
      data={null}
      ListHeaderComponent={
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
          // Added the component and navigator here because of scrolling capabilities
          <UserInfo />
          <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Images" component={ImageScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="TaggedImages" component={TaggedImageScreen} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </View>
      }
    />
  </>
)
```

**Image Screen**

```js
const ImageScreen = () => (
  <>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <Image src={item} />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </>
)
```

**Tagged Image Screen**

```js
const TaggedImageScreen = () => (
  <>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
          <Image src={item} />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </>
)
```

There's a couple questions/issues with this:

The height of the Tab Navigator is not dynamic to its respected component - meaning, if I have 3 images in **Image Screen component**, and 10 images in **Tagged Screen component**, the height will expand to the **Tagged screen** component (for both)

The reason for the FlatList in my Profile Component is because I want to be able to scroll the  component (similar to Instagram's profile).

So this brings to the next question: Is having the Tab Navigator in the List Header Component of the FlatList the best method to doing something similar to IG? Is there another way I should handle this feature?

Comment: There is no clean way of implementing this behavior as far as I am aware. With every hack you might think of (like nesting ScrollViews, or manually animating position of tabbar, or cutting tab content depending on which one is active, etc) there are always  going to be drawbacks. Either tabbar resets height when you switch tabs, or tabs take height of the highest tab, or tabs can be swiped to while being scrolled out of view, or no swipe transitions between tabs

Comment: have you found any answer ?